# <xsl:copy-of select="..."/> weirdness (or how to convert an attribute to a string in XPath 1.0)

Tags: xslt-1.0

ok, imaging a scenario where you want to make an element `Foo` that sometimes contains text, and sometimes contains an element e.g.

so sometimes the output needs to look like this (I'm embedding a `sortOrder` element)

```
<root>
  <Foo>
    <sortOrder value="3" />
  </Foo>
  <Foo>
    <sortOrder value="2" />
  </Foo>
  <Foo>
    <sortOrder value="2" />
  </Foo>
</root>
```

and sometimes it needs to be a simple text value like this

```
<root>
  <Foo>3</Foo>
  <Foo>2</Foo>
  <Foo>2</Foo>
</root>
```

(horrid yes, I didnt invent the schema)

so lets make up some input....

```
<root>
  <element>
    <sortOrder value="3"/>
  </element>
  <element>
     <sortOrder value="2"/>
  </element>
  <element>
     <sortOrder value="2"/>
  </element>
</root>
```

and write a template that makes the Foo element

```
   <xsl:template name="makeFoo">
      <xsl:param name="value"/>
      <Foo>
         <xsl:copy-of select="$value"/>
      </Foo>
   </xsl:template>
```

and here's the whole xslt for the 1st example, that works!!

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <root>
         <xsl:for-each select="root/element">
            <xsl:call-template name="makeFoo">
               <xsl:with-param name="value" select="sortOrder"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </root>
   </xsl:template>
   
   <xsl:template name="makeFoo">
      <xsl:param name="value"/>
      <Foo>
         <xsl:copy-of select="$value"/>
      </Foo>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

lets try the obvious with the 2nd output....(using the same 'library function makeFoo)

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <root>
         <xsl:for-each select="root/element">
            <xsl:call-template name="makeFoo">
               <xsl:with-param name="value" select="sortOrder/@value"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </root>
   </xsl:template>
   
   <xsl:template name="makeFoo">
      <xsl:param name="value"/>
      <Foo>
         <xsl:copy-of select="$value"/>
      </Foo>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

ah....almost....this does this..

it copies the attribute...clever...but not what I want.

```
<root>
  <Foo value="3" />
  <Foo value="2" />
  <Foo value="2" />
</root>
```

So how do I get what I want....

I tried...

```
<xsl:with-param name="value" select="sortOrder/@value/text()"/>
```

nope (unsurprisingly, there is no text node there)

this..

```
<xsl:with-param name="value">
   <xsl:value-of select="sortOrder/@value"/>
</xsl:with-param>
```

does work!!!!

presumably we are forcing xsl to generate a text node that is passed and then copied.

but is there a way to do this in the select? i.e. in the XPath expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An attribute does not have a child text node. To get the *string-value* of an attribute, you should be using the `xsl:value-of` instruction. If you must do it with `xsl:copy` (why??), you will first need to convert the attribute to string. In your example, that would (probably) mean:

```
<xsl:with-param name="value" select="string(sortOrder/@value)"/>
```

I hope this answers your question, which I find very confusing.

Comment: thanks....I did think of xs:string, but thats xslt 2+...
tbh, its not my code, but the 'copy-of' is there for the element use case

Comment: its confusing because the answer is so simple?